# tkinter keep a handle alive

Tags: python, tkinter

Hey there I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk
else:
    import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg


def draw_figure(canvas, figure, loc=(0, 0)):
    """ Draw a matplotlib figure onto a Tk canvas

    loc: location of top-left corner of figure on canvas in pixels.
    Inspired by matplotlib source: lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py
    """
    figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasAgg(figure)
    figure_canvas_agg.draw()
    figure_x, figure_y, figure_w, figure_h = figure.bbox.bounds
    figure_w, figure_h = int(figure_w), int(figure_h)
    photo = tk.PhotoImage(master=canvas, width=figure_w, height=figure_h)

    # Position: convert from top-left anchor to center anchor
    canvas.create_image(loc[0] + figure_w/2, loc[1] + figure_h/2, image=photo)

    # Unfortunately, there's no accessor for the pointer to the native renderer
    tkagg.blit(photo, figure_canvas_agg.get_renderer()._renderer, colormode=2)

    # Return a handle which contains a reference to the photo object
    # which must be kept live or else the picture disappears
    return photo

# Create a canvas
w, h = 300, 200
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("A figure in a canvas")
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=w, height=h)
canvas.pack()

# Generate some example data
X = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 50)
Y = np.sin(X)

# Create the figure we desire to add to an existing canvas
fig = mpl.figure.Figure(figsize=(2, 1))
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
ax.plot(X, Y)

# Keep this handle alive, or else figure will disappear
fig_x, fig_y = 100, 100
fig_photo = draw_figure(canvas, fig, loc=(fig_x, fig_y))
fig_w, fig_h = fig_photo.width(), fig_photo.height()

# Add more elements to the canvas, potentially on top of the figure
canvas.create_line(200, 50, fig_x + fig_w / 2, fig_y + fig_h / 2)
canvas.create_text(200, 50, text="Zero-crossing", anchor="s")
```

Code from here:
https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_canvas_sgskip.html

However I would like to draw different figures in a function. But when I try to do that my handle always dies and I do not see any figure on my tkinter....

**Any ideas how to do keep a handle alive inside a function?**

Comment: The usual solution is to store a reference to the image as an attribute of the widget that will display it - `canvas.photo = photo` perhaps.  If you want multiple plots in the same canvas, you'll need a slightly different approach, perhaps a list as an attribute of the canvas, then `canvas.photos.append(photo)`.  (Don't forget to clear that list if you clear the canvas, or you'll eventually run out of memory.)

Comment: Works thanks so much :)